# help in some linux commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, partitioning, disk-space

I need help in some linux commands regarding disk space.

When i see disk space using " df -h " it list all partitions with space left in percentage.
But here are few things i need to know more .

1. If i need to see which partition the particular dir is. For example if i want to see " /var/www/ " 's partition .
2. And If i want to see how much space left in particular partition .

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just add the directory in question to the command line.

For instance `df /home/dspillett` will tell me the amount of space available on the partition mounted as `/home` (which happens to contain `/home/dspillett`).

`df` will derive which filesystem the named directory is within and show you space stats for that. You can also use `df .` to find the available/used/free space on the filesystem containing your current working directory, whatever that happens to be.